# Pass output from class instance as input to another

Tags: python, numpy

I have this code:

```
import numpy as np

class B():
    def __init__(self, a,b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

class Criteria():
    def __init__(self, method, minimum, maximum, measures=None):
        self.method = method
        self.minimum = minimum
        self.maximum = maximum
        self.measures = measures if measures is not None else None

    def calcs(self):
        if self.measures is not None:
            for x in self.measures:
                if (x.a > self.minimum and x.a < self.maximum):
                    x.a = 999
        return self.measures

    def avg(self):
        if self.measures is not None:
            return np.average([x.value for x in self.measures])
        else:
            return np.average(3)# Here should be the result where None is defined
                                # Now I put just an arbitrary number

class Evaluate():
    def __init__(self, criteria):
        self.criteria = criteria


testdata = np.array([Evaluate(
        np.array([Criteria('V', 1,100, 

                np.array([B(100, 0.1),
                          B(11, 0.3),
                          B(300, 0.2),
                          B(33, 0.1)],dtype=object)
                ),

                Criteria('AVG', 22, 220, None)])

)])


for x in testdata:
    for idx, el in enumerate(x.criteria):
        if el.method == 'V':
            el.calcs() # this result must be passed as input to the `el.avg()`
        if el.method == 'AVG':
            el.avg()
```

I have a class `B` which holds some data (a and b fields).

I am loading these data to the `Criteria` class in order to pass through the criteria and change accordingly.

Then, the `Evaluate` class will hold all the above.

I am using `measures=None` to the Criteria class because in the case for example for the `avg` function , I may have not measurements to calculate on them the average, but I may have (this is my case) measurements from previous Criteria class on which I am applying the average.

Now, what I want to accomplish is this.

Load initially the data :

```
B(100, 0.1),
B(11, 0.3),
B(300, 0.2),
B(33, 0.1)
```

These data, by passing the criteria (by running the `calcs` function) , will chage to :

```
 B(100, 0.1),
 B(999, 0.3),
 B(300, 0.2),
 B(999, 0.1)
```

Now, the above data (which is the result/output from the first criteria, must be passed as input to the second criteria and compute the average value using the `avg` function.I don't know if this is possible without having any argument in the `avg` function . Just have the `self`.

So, my finaly result will be the value 599.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a modification of your script.  Mainly I added `repr`.  But I also changed the `None` case for `measures` to an empty list `[]`:

```
import numpy as np

class B():
    def __init__(self, a,b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'B(%s, %s)'%(self.a, self.b)

class Criteria():
    def __init__(self, method, minimum, maximum, measures=None):
        self.method = method
        self.minimum = minimum
        self.maximum = maximum
        self.measures = measures   # may be None

   def __repr__(self):
        # **edit** work with None
        if self.measures is None:
            measures = 'measures: None'
        else:
            measures = [' measures:[']
            for m in self.measures:
                measures.append('   {}'.format(m))
            measures.append('    ]')
            measures = '\n'+ '\n'.join(measures)
        return 'C({0.method},{0.minimum},{0.maximum}, {1})'.format(self, measures)

    def calcs(self):
        if self.measures is not None:
            for x in self.measures:
                if (x.a > self.minimum and x.a < self.maximum):

                x.a = 999
    return self.measures

    def avg(self, calcs=None):
        # **edit** work with None and calcs
        if calcs is None:
            calcs = self.measures
        if calcs is None:
            return 'none'
        elif len(calcs)==0:
            return '[]'
        else:
            return np.average([x.a for x in calcs])

class Evaluate():
    def __init__(self, criteria):
        self.criteria = criteria
    def __repr__(self):
        #return 'E({})'.format(self.criteria)
        astr = 'Evaluate \n'
        for c in self.criteria:
            astr += '{}\n'.format(c)
        return astr
```

---

Consider making a group of `Criteria` objects.  An `AVG` has to know, in some way or other, which `measures` it uses.  One way is the `measures` parameter used during construction.

```
b1 = np.array([B(100, 0.1),
    B(11, 0.3),
    B(300, 0.2),
    B(33, 0.1)],dtype=object)
b2 = np.array([B(1, 0.1), B(2,.5)])
c1 = Criteria('V', 1, 100, b1)
c2 = Criteria('V', 2, 200, b2)
c3 = Criteria('AVG', 22, 220, None)
c4 = Criteria('AVG', 22, 220, c2.measures)
c5 = Criteria('AVG', 22, 222, c1.measures)
```

---

**edit** change the iteration to save the last `calcs` result, and use that if the `AVG` measures is None.  `C.avg` now takes an optional parameter.

```
last_calcs = None
for c in  alist:
    if c.method=='V':
        last_calcs = c.calcs()
        print('calcs', c.measures)
    if c.method=='AVG':
        if c.measures is None:
            avg = c.avg(last_calcs)
        else:
            avg = c.avg()
        print('AVG', avg)
```

with:

```
alist = [c3,c1,c3,c2,c3,c4, c5]
```

this produces:

```
evaluate
AVG none         # c3 with nothing preceeding
calcs [B(100, 0.1) B(999, 0.3) B(300, 0.2) B(999, 0.1)]
AVG 599.5        # c3 following c1
calcs [B(1, 0.1) B(2, 0.5)]
AVG 1.5          # c3 following c2
AVG 1.5          # c4 with same measures as c2
AVG 599.5        # c5 with same measures as c1
```

Comment: Hi,thanks for help!I can't see how to make `C(AVG.` to return the average of `100,999,300,999` which is just the value 999.Also, you say `So the V action evaluates the averages, returns them but also changes the B object` but the `V` action has nothing to do with averages.It calls the `calcs` function which applies some criteria to the measures.Then,from these new values ,I have to extract the avegage by calling `avg` function.As for putting `None` in the second `Criteria` , `C(AVG,22,220,None)` is because I don't know how to handle this.I want to pass instead of None, the result from `calcs`.

Comment: If `C=Criteria...`, then `C.calcs()` changes its `measures`.  `C.avg()` returns a value based on those `measures`. Your example applies `calc` to one list of measures, avg to another empty list.  To do both you'd have to pass the same list to two different `Criteria` objects.

Comment: I am supplying a list to a criteria.The list changes if I call the `calcs` method.Then, I have to supply this new list to the second criteria in order to compute the average.I hope it is clear

Comment: Your solution as I understand , is that If I want to compute the avg method, I have to call first the calcs on the list and then the avg on the same list,so call just one criteria `C(avg...thelist)` and when `method==avg`, call first `calcs` and then `avg` , right?But I don't want this.

Comment: The `avg` method could include a `self.calcs()` statement.  Or in the testdata loop perform both `el.calcs()` and `el.avg()`.

Comment: Hmm.This is not what I want though..So, you are saying that what I want is not possible?

Comment: See my edits for further exploration on how to link Criteria instances.

Comment: OK, I understand what you say but I thought of something like [this](http://pastebin.com/8WQbmBhQ).What do you say?Thanks. (I have a mistake, instead of  `temp = el.measures` ,use `temp = el.calcs()`

Comment: I've changed the last iteration so it can save a `calcs`, which can be used by a `None` avg Criteria.  That required a change to the `avg` method, and the Criteria `__repr__`.

Comment: Thanks!Very nice solution!One question.In `avg` function you have `if calcs is None:
            calcs = self.measures
        if calcs is None:
            return 'none'` , so 2 times you define `if calcs is None`.I can delete the `if calcs is None: return 'none' ` ?

Comment: And in the `Criteria, init method` you have ` self.measures = measures`.Can we leave the `self.measures= measures if measures is not None else None`?It is reduntant in that case? (upvoted)

Comment: The double None test is needed for first `c3` use - `avg` without a prior `last_calcs`.  The `if none` test for `self measures` looks redundant to me, but is harmless.  These are details that should resolve with thorough testing.

Comment: I hope I am not disturbing you..I have opened a [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42415822/cycle-through-previous-class-instances-results) which is the nest step from where we left it.So, if you can help,I 'll appreciate,thanks!(and sorry for the comments)