# cycle through previous class instances results

Tags: python, numpy

This is a continuation from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42321371/pass-output-from-class-instance-as-input-to-another).

I have a class B which holds some data (a and b fields).

I am loading these data to the Criteria class in order to pass through the criteria and change accordingly calling the functions `avg`, `func`, `calcs`.

Then , I call the function `P` to start running the program with the data.

The code:

```
import numpy as np

class B():
    def __init__(self, a,b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'B(%s, %s)'%(self.a, self.b)


class Criteria():
    def __init__(self, method, minimum, maximum, measures=None):
        self.method = method
        self.minimum = minimum
        self.maximum = maximum
        self.measures = measures  

    def __repr__(self):
        if self.measures is None:
            measures = 'measures: None'
        else:
            measures = [' measures:[']
            for m in self.measures:
                measures.append('   {}'.format(m))
            measures.append('    ]')
            measures = '\n'+ '\n'.join(measures)
        return 'C({0.method},{0.minimum},{0.maximum}, {1})'.format(self, measures)


    def calcs(self):
        """ Update the `a` attribute from B class object according to 
         conditions
        """
        if self.measures is not None:
            for x in self.measures:
                if (x.a > self.minimum and x.a < self.maximum):
                    x.a = 999
        return self.measures

    def avg(self, calcs=None):
        """Return the average of values"""
        if calcs is None:
            calcs = self.measures
        if calcs is None:
            return 'none'
        elif len(calcs)==0:
            return '[]'
        else:
            return np.average([x.a for x in calcs])

    def func(self,calcs=None):
        """Return the minimum is input is array or multiple by 1000
        if input is a number"""
        if calcs is None:
            calcs = self.measures
        if calcs is None:
            return 'none'
        #elif len(calcs) == 0:
        #    return '[]'
        else:

            if isinstance(calcs, np.ndarray):
                return np.amin([x.a for x in calcs])
            else:
                return calcs*1000                       

def P(alist):

    # use these variables to hold the result of the corresponding execution
    # use them in the list loop in order to be able to obtain a result from a `Criteria` evaluation
    # and use it as input to the next
    last_calcs_values = None
    last_calcs_avg = None
    last_calcs_m = None

    for c in  alist:

        if c.method=='V':
            last_calcs_values = c.calcs()
            #print('calcs', last_calcs_values)
            yield last_calcs_values
        if c.method=='AVG':
            if c.measures is None:
                last_calcs_avg = c.avg(last_calcs_values)
            else:
                last_calcs_avg = c.avg()
            #print('AVG', last_calcs_avg)
            yield last_calcs_avg
        if c.method == 'M':
            if c.measures is None:
                last_calcs_m = c.func(last_calcs_avg)
            else:
                last_calcs_m = c.func()
            #print('M',last_calcs_m)
            yield last_calcs_m
```

If I use the data:

```
 b1 = np.array([B(10, 0.1), B(200,.5)])

c1 = Criteria('V', 1, 100, b1)
c2 = Criteria('AVG', 22, 220, None)
c3 = Criteria('M', 22, 220, None)

alist = [c1,c2,c3]

for i in P(alist):
    print(i)
```

I receive:

```
[B(999, 0.1) B(200, 0.5)]
599.5
599500.0
```

which is correct.But it works because the code in `P` function is hardcoded..

So,

1) My data , `c1,c2,c3` uses the methods `V,AVG,M` in that order.

So, in the `P` function , I used :

```
   yield last_calcs_values

   last_calcs_avg = c.avg(last_calcs_values)
   yield last_calcs_avg

   last_calcs_m = c.func(last_calcs_avg)
   yield last_calcs_m
```

the same order (hardcoded).

My question is how can I use this code for any order.I must somehow check what the previous method value is and put that in the argument (instead of putting c.func(last_calcs_avg)

2) Inside the `func` I have commented out the  lines:

```
    #elif len(calcs) == 0:
    #    return '[]'
```

because if I run the code , it gives :  `object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len()` .

I tried to check similar with the check I have later in `func` :
`if isinstance(calcs, np.ndarray):`

but with no success.

3) Is there a way to obtain only the last result?

So, instead of :

```
[B(999, 0.1) B(200, 0.5)]
599.5
599500.0
```

obtain :

```
599500.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read `P` correctly it maintains 3 'state' variables.  The 3 if clauses can called in any order (and I think could have been written with a `if,ifthen,ifthen,else` syntax since `c.method` only matches one (for each `c`.

But the order of the objects in the list will determine values.  An `AVG` object will use what ever values were set by the last `V` object.  Similarly the `M` will use the last `AVG`.  If pass an `AVG` first it will use the initial `None` values in its calc.

So sequence of `V1, AVG, M` will use `B` values that were set by `V1`.

In this sequence `V1, AVG, V2, M`, `M` uses values from the last `AVG` which was dependent on `V1`;

`avg` should not be returning strings if its values are being used by `func`, or at least the tests must match.  `[]` is an empty list with `len()` zero, but `'[]'` is a 2 character string, with `len` 2.

Similarly `None` is a unique value that you test with `is None`, while `'none'` is a 4 character string.  I used strings like that in earlier questions simply because we were printing the results of `avg`.  At the time we weren't using them for further calculations.

---

If you want to make sure that `AVG` and `M` use values from the last `V`, you need to add some logic:

```
 lastV, lastA, lastM = None,None,None
 if c.method=='V':
     lastV = <newV>
     lastA, lastM = None,None
 elif c.method=='A':
     if lastV is None:
        error
     else:
        lastA = <new A based on lastV>
 elif c.method=='M':
     if lastA is None:
        error
        <or update lastA>
     else:
        lastM = <new M based on lastA>
 else:
     error unknown c.method
```

So I am using `None` to indicate that the values are not valid.  In which case it should either raise an error, or it should calculate new values.  Done right it should ensure that both `AVG` and `M` will produce values based on the latest `V`.

---

From your pastebin:

```
def avg(self, calcs=None):
    """Return the average of values"""
    if calcs is None:          # fun called without argument
        calcs = self.measures  # get value stored in self
    if calcs is None:          # in case that too was None
        return '[]'            # I would return None or []
                               # '[]' is a useless string
    else:
        if hasattr(calcs,'__len__'):
            return np.average([x.a for x in calcs])
        else:
            return np.average(calcs)
```

What works in `np.average()` that doesn't have a `len`?  `len(np.arange(10))` runs, but doesn't have the `a` attribute

```
In [603]: avg(None,calcs=np.arange(10))
....
<ipython-input-602-48c9f6b255e1> in <listcomp>(.0)
      8     else:
      9         if hasattr(calcs,'__len__'):
---> 10             return np.average([x.a for x in calcs])
     11         else:
     12             return np.average(calcs)

AttributeError: 'numpy.int32' object has no attribute 'a'
```

That `__len__` between an array or list with `B` objects and other lists or arrays.  Maybe refine this to test dtype?  Or a try/except?

def avg(self, calcs=None):
    """Return the average of values"""
    ....
    else:
        try:
            return np.average([x.a for x in calcs])
        except AttributeError:
            return np.average(calcs)

```
In [606]: avg(None,calcs=np.arange(10))
Out[606]: 4.5
```

And list or array of `B` objects works:

```
In [609]: alist = [B(1,2),B(2,4),B(3,3)]
In [610]: avg(None, alist)
Out[610]: 2.0
In [611]: avg(None, np.array(alist))
Out[611]: 2.0
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer.The check I am doing [here](http://pastebin.com/2gK0yp3b) is correct?I am checking the case that `calcs` might be a number or an array.

Comment: Hmm.Nice! Thanks!(upvoted).And we can add another exception `except (AttributeError, TypeError)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you mean by not hardcoding `P`

> 3. Is there a way to obtain only the last result?

Yes. Obtain all the results, but only print the last one:

```
for i in P(alist): pass
print(i)
```

Comment: By hardcoding the code, I call every function according to the same order as the input `V,AVG,M`.When I call `V` , I obtain some results.When I next call `AVG`, I want the `AVG` method to be applied in the previous results (the ones I got from `V` method).Them , I want to call `M` on the results I got from previous ( the `AVG`) .In order to do so, I am using the `last_calcs` statements.But as you can see ,I call them explicitly in every case.For exampl if method is `AVG`, call `c.avg(last_calcs_values)`, but instead of `last_calcs_values` I have to find what method is before calling `AVG`

Comment: For obtaining the result by just passing the last one.This is the only way to do it?Is there a way to store the results (using return?)